# Media library: don't include profile pics or remove from library without deleting

Tags: 7, media

Our site allows users to create a profile avatar. We are also using the [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module, version 2.19, which includes a media library. The library is useful, however, all of our users' profile images populate the media library, which is tens of thousands of images. I don't want our users to be able to select these and other images from the media library when writing their blogs.

Is there a way to exclude these from getting added or is there a way to remove images from the library without deleting the image altogether?

Comment: The only way I know to do this would be making a new media type to segregate the usage and purpose of that media. But I think this introduces other issues particularly with the WYSIWYG Media Embed which cannot determine which media type it is based on mime alone, since now you have more than one type using images. Another fix is not using anything but the generic image field for the user picture, and not media.

Comment: You're on to something with using generic image field. I never intended on using the media field for the avatar builder. I will look into that. Do you happen to know the difference in field names?